# I cannot put images in firestorage since it asks for a file

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I've been working on an app with some apis in flutter, one of the is [flutter_signature_pad](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_signature_pad#-example-tab-), since this api saves a signature as an image I cannot seem to save it in firestorage since it only accepts file types.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
onPressed: () async {
                      final sign = _sign.currentState;
                      //retrieve image data, do whatever you want with it
                      final image = await sign.getData();
                      StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
                          storageReference.putFile(image);
                      await uploadTask.onComplete;
                      print('File Uploaded');
                      sign.clear();
                    }
```

Comment: What is image? try print(image.runtimeType) and tell me what do you get

Comment: Well, the funny thing about that is that it just prints "Image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final image =
          await sign.getData();
await image.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(
          byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
```

or You can do is save image to a directory and then after using it delete it then there you can use this

```
final file =
          File('${systemTempDir.path}/$imageName.jpeg');
      await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(
          byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
```

I used [This Reference](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-storage-in-flutter-9f23b04291e5) and If you see in the example of the library [Flutter Signature pad](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_signature_pad#-example-tab-) they also write or encode data in a similar format

Comment: Thank you so much! The first solution is definitely what I'm looking for since I don't quite know how to save the image to a directory, though when I try to use writeAsBytes() I get an undefined method problem, I've tried to import dart:io since that seemed like the solution but It seems like It wasn't

Comment: Actually the solution worked wonders after I understood some of the methods, thank you so much, you are a life saver!

Comment: Glad I could help : )